# Spring MVC: loading static image

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, resources

I'm trying to crate ImageController that contains following method:

```
public byte[] getProfileImage(@PathVariable String username) {
    byte[] tmp = null;
    tmp = imageService.getProfileImage(username).getImagefile();
    return tmp;
}
```

Now if imageService return empty image file, i would like to load image from webapp/WEB-INF/img/ folder. I tried googling this but didn't find any answer that i could get working.

Another way to do this would be loading image file in imageService class, but i don't how could i load image from there either.

I would appreciate quite specific answer. Im not very skilled with spring. Especially configurations are not very clear to me.

Comment: Your question seems to be "How do I load a static file from `WEB-INF`?" rather than anything about spring mvc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the method [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), which loads a resource from a path starting at the webapp's root folder:

```
 InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/img/someImage.jpg");
```